# Typecast for delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have created delegates with the same signature like function passed for Thread class job:

```
    public delegate void myDelegateForThread();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myDelegateForThread del = thrFunc;


        Thread t = new Thread( del);
        t.Start();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { Console.WriteLine("Main thread " +i); }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static void thrFunc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { Console.WriteLine("Secondary thread " + i); }
    }
```

But compiler is not happy I don't pass `ThreadStart` for `Thread` constructor. I know how to solve problem in this case, but my question is can I do typecast for delegates if they have the same signature?

Comment: Please show us how `myDelegateForThread` is declared. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated code with delegate

Comment: What do you mean the "compiler is not happy" - what error do you get exactly?  There shouldn't be any problem creating a Thread using thrFunc as the ThreadStart parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the following, no it does not work:

```
public delegate int MyDelegate1(double param);
public delegate int MyDelegate2(double param);
public int MyFunction(double p) { return 1; }

MyDelegate1 del1 = MyFunction;
MyDelegate2 del2 = (MyDelegate2)del1;
```

The delegate is in that way the same as any other type and there is no inheritance or interface relation -> they can't be typecasted to each other even if the signature matches.

What does work is wrapping it in a new delegate:

```
MyDelegate2 del2 = new MyDelegate2(del1);
```